# Adding a JPanel from a class to a JFrame in main class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am trying to add this panel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class TopPanel extends JPanel{
    public TopPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Course Lookup GUI");
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

To a frame like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class CourseGUI extends JFrame{
    public CourseGUI() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setLocation(200,200);

        TopPanel    tPan = new TopPanel();
        MiddlePanel mPan = new MiddlePanel();

        this.add(tPan);
        this.add(mPan);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        CourseGUI cGUI = new CourseGUI();
    }
}
```

But nothing is adding to the frame, and I'm getting an empty window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your class already extends JPanel, there is no need to create another panel. Just add the label to the class itself

```
class TopPanel extends JPanel{
    public TopPanel() {
        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Course Lookup GUI");
        add( label );
        //panel.add(label);
        //panel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I also agree with Reimeus's comment. There is no need to extend JPanel to do this functionality. Just do:

```
JPanel tPan = new JPanel;
JLabel label = new JLabel("Course Lookup GUI");
tPan.add(label);
this.add( tPan );
```

Or even easier, since you are just adding one component to the panel, there is no need to even create the panel. Just do:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Course Lookup GUI");
this.add( label );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your `panel` to the container in `TopPanel`

```
add(panel);
```

As you're not currently adding any new functionality to the `JPanel` you could simply use a direct instance of `JPanel` instead of sub-classing. Calling `panel.setVisible(true)` is unnecessary. Swing will make the required components visible when the top level window is made visible.